# Can Odoo Website Framework be great alternative for Odoo POS?

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale, odoo-website

Odoo released it's website framework which is very easy and powerful. ( Great thanks to Odoo Team !! )

Now we all Odoo experts need to think on whether a Website framework can be good alternative for POS ?

**Website benefits are listed as below,**

- It's very easy to add & Integrate third party CSS and JS in Website.
- You can make your custom design quickly in Website compare to POS.
- POS developed because the purpose of it was, some of the user friendly features not possible / difficult over back end side, so Odoo team has developed custom POS framework with specific JS & CSS. But as of now, since website framework released, you can easily add all the custom front end features so why there is need for POS framework ?
- Though website framework is dependent on Qweb templates, if POS can be move over website framework then it will be easy for end users to make quick changes on POS too. Because Qweb templates are more easy to handle with. ( We are very much aware on the fact that in Odoo V9, POS is moved on Qweb templates. )
- Website menus are also secured by user wise Access rights so I don't think there will be any kind of problem with authentication. ( User wise login and different actions )
- POS changes are very difficult because that framework is somehow based on "Web" framework of Odoo. So definitely any custom design will be hard to implement compare to website framework.
- Website page can also work in Offline mode if JS is designed like that. So that is also not a problem in case of POS can be moved to website.

Just like,

> Example 1 : Odoo deprecated RML and moved it's reporting structure to
>   Qweb framework, it will be good to say bye bye to POS framework and
>   merge it into website framework.
>
> Example 2 : As Odoo given the feature of barcode scanning from website
>   for Delivery Orders and Incoming Shipment, if POS is from website
>   framework, then it will be easy to integrate it with Barcode scanning.

( However we haven't any problem or neither we are against with POS framework but as Odoo is growing day by day, one type of development framework will be easy to manage rather then separate frameworks like POS and website. )

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Current implementation is the Odoo POS using same technology as Web Framework, Qweb, Backbonejs, And Kinf of Internal Framework and work as same mechanism.

Using **Web Framework** for POS is not good idea with many reasons :

- POS and Web Framework Share same Technologies (qWeb, Backbone, underscore) so technically their no difference in them.
- POS has offline working  abilities which invites complexity now if you think you want to use Web Framework you will end up large implementation of something complex which will be similar.
- POS has hardware integration which has to-do lower level hardware integration, which require special handling and you don't wanna mix your low level API to Web giving opportunity to exploit system through their (I know we can do that but not worth)
- POS has very specific implementation like brocade reader and magnetic hardware readers  which needs special implementation, with Web you start doing this then you will end up creating your own framework (as I said both share same tech.)
- Warehouse brocade interface will be moved to the web by odoo for sure, as in v9 barcode interface is gone.
- Odoo Point of Sale will facilitate your inventory management

Bests